# Gradle exception org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceCreationException

Tags: gradle, blockchain, hyperledger

Why gradle clean/build failed?
I am trying [this link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-chaincode-for-java-developers/index.html) to install and run the blockchain. I have gradle installed in my system. 
when i run the command given in tutorial
`gradle -b build.gradle clean` it throws

> org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceCreationException

I have given all the permission to the folders. But still confused why this is coming?

FYI stacktrace--

> Exception is:
>   org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceCreationException: Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:797)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:748)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:574)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:623)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:761)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:747)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:574)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:623)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:761)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:747)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:574)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:623)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.doGet(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:344)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:325)
>           at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.doNewInstance(DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.java:174)
>           at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.newInstance(DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.java:106)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:40)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
>           at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
>           at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
>           at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:57)
>           at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
>           at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
>           at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
>           at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
>           at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
>           at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
>           at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:29)
>           at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
>           at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
>           at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:45)
>           at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>           at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
>           at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>           at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>           at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>   Caused by: org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceCreationException: Could not create service of type CrossBuildFileHashCache using BuildSessionScopeServices.createCrossBuildFileHashCache().
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:797)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:748)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:574)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:623)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:761)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:747)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:574)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:623)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:761)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:747)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:574)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:623)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.doGet(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:344)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:329)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ParentServices.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1111)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$CachingProvider.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:970)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$CompositeProvider.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1034)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext$4.apply(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1356)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext$4.apply(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1353)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext.getServiceProvider(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1297)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext.find(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1285)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.getServiceProvider(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:350)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.doGet(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:341)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:329)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ParentServices.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1111)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$CachingProvider.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:970)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$CompositeProvider.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1034)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext$4.apply(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1356)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext$4.apply(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1353)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext.getServiceProvider(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1297)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext.find(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1285)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.bind(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:722)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.prepare(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:628)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:642)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$OwnServices.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:465)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$CachingProvider.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:970)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$CompositeProvider.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1034)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext$4.apply(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1356)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext$4.apply(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1353)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext.getServiceProvider(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1297)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext.find(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1285)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.bind(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:722)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.prepare(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:628)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:642)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$OwnServices.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:465)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$CachingProvider.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:970)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$CompositeProvider.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1034)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext$4.apply(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1356)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext$4.apply(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1353)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext.getServiceProvider(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1297)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$DefaultLookupContext.find(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1285)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.getServiceProvider(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:350)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.doGet(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:341)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:325)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.BuildScopeServices.defaultScriptPluginFactory(BuildScopeServices.java:290)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory(BuildScopeServices.java:282)
>           at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.invoke(ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.java:35)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:795)
>           ... 60 more
>   Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Failed to create parent directory '/home/cvllp3/mychain/fabric/.gradle' when creating directory '/home/cvllp3/mychain/fabric/.gradle/4.2/fileHashes'
>           at org.gradle.util.GFileUtils.mkdirs(GFileUtils.java:271)
>           at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:56)
>           at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:32)
>           at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory.doOpen(DefaultCacheFactory.java:90)
>           at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory.open(DefaultCacheFactory.java:64)
>           at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheRepository$PersistentCacheBuilder.open(DefaultCacheRepository.java:123)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CrossBuildFileHashCache.(CrossBuildFileHashCache.java:41)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.BuildSessionScopeServices.createCrossBuildFileHashCache(BuildSessionScopeServices.java:191)
>           at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.invoke(ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.java:35)
>           at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:795)
>           ... 118 more

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Look at this answer [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/an-error-happens-when-gradlew-assemble-command-is-run-on-linux/4962), seems like file permission error in the directory.

> org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Failed to create parent directory
>   '/home/cvllp3/mychain/fabric/.gradle' when creating directory
>   '/home/cvllp3/mychain/fabric/.gradle/4.2/fileHashes'